# Find actual Data Type in MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to find out the:

1. ***data type***
2. ***length***

of a column in table in PHP. I noticed that I could do that from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` as well as my own table as:

```
$query = $link->query("SELECT * FROM `events` LIMIT 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_fields($query);
foreach($row as $field){
    print_r($field);
}
```

The response is definitely an array. I pretty much found out everything like:

```
( 
    [name] => id 
    [orgname] => id 
    [table] => events 
    [orgtable] => events 
    [def] => 
    [db] => myliveca_baikalpik 
    [catalog] => def 
    [max_length] => 1 
    [length] => 11 
    [charsetnr] => 63 
    [flags] => 49667 
    [type] => 3 
    [decimals] => 0 
)
```

So far at this point I have the `length` of the data but the data type still seems to be encoded (or whatever) represented in number as:

- 3 for int
- 11 for time
- 252 for text

How do I backtrace this?

Comment: Nice research. Do you mean that you are looking for a resource that matched the integer value `type `  with the actual `data type`?

Comment: @user3581203 Yes exactly. Or some methods that do that for me easily :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran through some crazy loops and found out the complete trail (excluding the grometric and enums)

```
1   tinyint
2   smallint
9   mediumint
3   int
8   bigint
246 decimal
4   float
5   double
5   real
16  bit
1   boolean
8   serial
10  date
12  datetime
7   timestamp
11  time
13  year
254 char
253 varchar
252 tinytext
252 text
252 mediumtext
252 longtext
254 binary
253 varbinary
252 tinyblob
252 mediumblob
252 blob
252 longblob
```

Comment: The blob numbers are wrong, see Whirlwind's answer.

Answer (score 5):

You are probably looking for [predefined mysqli constants](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php#mysqli.constants):

```
["MYSQLI_TYPE_DECIMAL"]=>
  int(0)
  ["MYSQLI_TYPE_TINY"]=>
  int(1)
  ["MYSQLI_TYPE_SHORT"]=>
  int(2)
  ["MYSQLI_TYPE_LONG"]=>
  int(3)
  ["MYSQLI_TYPE_FLOAT"]=>
  int(4)
  ["MYSQLI_TYPE_DOUBLE"]=>
  int(5)
  ["MYSQLI_TYPE_NULL"]=>
  int(6)
  ["MYSQLI_TYPE_TIMESTAMP"]=>
  int(7)
  ["MYSQLI_TYPE_LONGLONG"]=>
  int(8)
  ["MYSQLI_TYPE_INT24"]=>
  int(9)
  ["MYSQLI_TYPE_DATE"]=>
  int(10)
  ["MYSQLI_TYPE_TIME"]=>
  int(11)
  ["MYSQLI_TYPE_DATETIME"]=>
  int(12)
  ["MYSQLI_TYPE_YEAR"]=>
  int(13)
  ["MYSQLI_TYPE_NEWDATE"]=>
  int(14)
  ["MYSQLI_TYPE_ENUM"]=>
  int(247)
  ["MYSQLI_TYPE_SET"]=>
  int(248)
  ["MYSQLI_TYPE_TINY_BLOB"]=>
  int(249)
  ["MYSQLI_TYPE_MEDIUM_BLOB"]=>
  int(250)
  ["MYSQLI_TYPE_LONG_BLOB"]=>
  int(251)
  ["MYSQLI_TYPE_BLOB"]=>
  int(252)
  ["MYSQLI_TYPE_VAR_STRING"]=>
  int(253)
  ["MYSQLI_TYPE_STRING"]=>
  int(254)
  ["MYSQLI_TYPE_CHAR"]=>
  int(1)
```

You can find values of all predefined constants with:

```
<?php

echo "<pre>";
   var_dump(get_defined_constants());
echo "</pre>";
?>
```