# Sorting multiple date formats

Tags: php, sorting, mysqli

In database I've got column `date_of_premiere` (type: INT). Passing the validation that column can store three "types" of values:

YYYY (e.g. 2016, when there's no info about specific month and day)

YYYYMM (e.g. 201511, when there's no info about specific day)

YYYYMMDD (e.g. 20151101)

I've got problem with sorting, becouse when I'm try to sort that column...

```
$query = $this->db->query(" SELECT * from table order by `date_of_premiere ");
```

... records with format YYYY will always first.

When I fetch the data, I can do some kind of workaround...

```
$dates =[];
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
{
    if(strlen($row['date_of_premiere']) == 4)
    {
         $dates[] .= intval($row['date_of_premiere'] .'0000');
    } else if (strlen($row['date_of_premiere']) == 6)
    {
         $dates[] .= intval($row['date_of_premiere'] .'00');
    } else 
    {
         $dates[] .= intval($row['date_of_premiere']);
    }
}
```

...then I can do `asort($dates)`...

```
// input values: 2015, 2016, 201511, 20151101
// example output with correct sorting:
Array
(
    [1] => 20150000
    [0] => 20151100
    [3] => 20151101
    [2] => 20160000
)
```

... but I'm curious is there way to sort `date_of_premiere` using mysqli query only.

Comment: I guess it will be a bit complicated to achieve. I've found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640428/find-actual-data-type-in-mysqli) that there is datetime column type in MySQLi. Maybe it would be good idea to use it instead of INT? I know You don't always know the full date, but You could add some booleans to indicate missing info, and sorting would work by default :)

Comment: I think, I found quite simple solution. I changed type of mysql column to varchar.It seems that now I can sort values, as expected: array([1] => 2015 [0] => 201511 [3] => 20151101 [2] => 2016) Anyway, thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can order by the dates' column casted as CHAR:

```
... ORDER BY CAST(date_of_premier AS CHAR(32))
```

Comment: Anyway, I would change the column to VARCHAR if you don't need MySQL to do any arithmetic operation with its values.